# convert interface to defined struct Golang

Tags: go, struct, interface, casting

I am working on a utility method lets say GetConfig(), which reads the config struct and return it to the caller. GetConfig() does not know what config it is going to read, but the caller knows the struct what it is going to receive.

In this regard, I have written a below utility program:

```
=========== yaml file data ==========
apiRouting:
  enableThrottling: true
  formFactor: 4
leasing:
  periodInSecs: 10
  preemptionEnable: false
=========== yaml file data ==========

func GetConfig() (interface{}, error) {
    fmt.Println("reading generic service config")
    viper.SetConfigName("service_config")
    viper.AddConfigPath("config/default")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var appConfig interface{}
    if err := viper.Unmarshal(&appConfig); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return appConfig, nil
}
```

Caller uses GetConfig() like this: (I have tried 2 options, nothing is working)

```
type ApiRouting struct {
    EnableThrottling bool  `json:"enableThrottling"`
    FormFactor       int32 `json:"formFactor"`
}

type Leasing struct {
    PeriodInSecs     int32 `json:"periodInSecs"`
    PreemptionEnable bool  `json:"preemptionEnable"`
}

type ServiceConfig struct {
    ApiRouting ApiRouting `json:"apiRouting"`
    Leasing    Leasing    `json:"leasing"`
}

// code snipped [option 1]
    tmpinterface := GetConfig()
    myconfig, ok := tmpinterface.(ServiceConfig)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal()
    } else {
        println(myconfig)
    }

// code snipped [option 2]
    tmpinterface := GetConfig()
    // Convert map to json string
    jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(tmpinterface)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    
    // Convert json string to struct
    var sc ServiceConfig
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &sc); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

I have verified that `tmpinterface` is getting the values correctly in both the cases, but finally `myconfig{}` struct is empty.

`tmpinterface` value is:

```
map[%!f(string=apirouting):map[%!f(string=enablethrottling):%!f(bool=true) %!f(string=formfactor):%!f(int=4)] %!f(string=leasing):map[%!f(string=periodinsecs):%!f(int=10) %!f(string=preemptionenable):%!f(bool=false)]]
```

Comment: `GetConfig` should accept an instance of the concrete config type, i.e. `var sc ServiceConfig; GetConfig(&sc)`.

Comment: @mkopriva: I cannot use the concrete type here. Because ```GetConfig```  code lies in the framework and various services will call it. Framework doesn't really need to know the concrete type. I am very close to my solution, its just I am not able to unmarshall it into the required struct.

Comment: `GetConfig` doesn't need to know the concrete type, it can accept `any` as argument, just like `json.Unmarshal` or `viper.Unmarshal`.

Comment: Something like this: https://go.dev/play/p/jshA4lk3Ero

Comment: Your `// code snipped [option 1]` will never ever work. You are passing `appConfig interface{}` to `viper.Unmarshal` and it therefore has no way of knowing that you would like it to decode the config into `ServiceConfig`. Your `// code snipped [option 2]` could work, but the target structs and the source configuration MUST be structured "compatibly" and the *case* of keys SHOULD be identical (i.e., `apirouting` != `apiRouting `).

Comment: @mkopriva: Really thanks, Any works like charm and it looks clean also. Learnt a good thing today.

Answer (score 1):

@mkopriva, thanks for a cleaner solution.

```
func GetConfig(appConfig any) error {
    fmt.Println("reading generic service config")
    viper.SetConfigName("service_config")
    viper.AddConfigPath("config/default")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := viper.Unmarshal(appConfig); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var sc ServiceConfig
    if err := GetConfig(&sc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sc)
}
```